# Backgroundimage is shown in Simulator but not on device

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I develop a action for the google assistant and want to add an background image. To do so, i added two pictures in the console under build -> theme customization. This Picures are also shown if I use the Simulator but when I try to the the action on an phone with google-assistant the picture is not shown. Is there any setting i missed to display the picture on the phone or is it not possible?

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found the answer?